# How to get the GivenName property into parameter

Tags: c#, powershell, c#-3.0, powershell-2.0

I am building an application in C# that can run PowerShell commands. Currently I am in the stage where I got the user properties into `PSObject`.

I want to get specific details from the user properties but I don't know how.

[image]

The problem is that inside the cmdlet I have the property `BaseObject` and inside it I have the properties `GivenName` and `Surname`.

I want to get `GivenName` into parameter but I don't know what kind of parameter. I tried to "Copy Expression" and I received:

```
((Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser)(cmdlet.BaseObject)).GivenName
```

But it is not recognized.

> No such class:
>   Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser

Do you have an idea how can I get the `GivenName` property into the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am little bit unsure on what you mean by get value GivenName into a parameter. If you just want the given name from the results then it is easy to get.

```
var givenName = cmdlet.Properties["GivenName"].Value;
```

If you looking to get all the properties then you can get it in `PSMemberInfoCollection`

```
 PSMemberInfoCollection<PSPropertyInfo> props = psObject.Properties;                       
 props.ToList().ForEach(x => {
   Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Value: {1}", x.Name,x.Value);                        
 });
```

If you are trying to convert `PSObject` into `ADUser` then you will have to load the assembly `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management` in your c# sharp code, then create an instance of ADUser from the `PSObject`

**Edit1:**

So if you want to get the groups or a particular group by index then. Again this just purely based upon hacks.  Use all the code with caution. Anyways you can use dynamic keyword to do something interesting.  First you can get the `GivenName` property just like that.  And then your MemberOf property will give you a ValueList which is of type Collection and you get property by an index or you can Enumerate over all the properties available to you.

```
dynamic adUser = psObject.BaseObject;
Console.WriteLine("GivenName: {0}, Surname: {1}",adUser.GivenName.ToString(),adUser.Surname.ToString());

dynamic memberof = psObject.Properties["MemberOf"].Value;    
var firstGroup = memberof.ValueList[0].ToString();
var allGroups = memberof.ValueList;
foreach (var item in allGroups)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Comment: it works.  
By the way, incase I want to get the groups from the MemberOf property.  
This is how it looks:
!http://imageshack.com/a/img839/9049/49ax.png  
I tried also  (cmdlet.Members["MemberOf"].Value).Value[0] But it doesn't provide me the group.

Comment: Check my edit1 that solves your issue. please mark it as answer if it solved your original issue. And you can ask another question so others can help you.

Comment: The dynamic solved it - thanks you! I just needed to change the building to .Net 4 Client Profile.
Why you asked me to use the code with caution ?

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell did you remember to reflect the assembly before running your command.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management');((Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser)(cmdlet.BaseObject)).GivenName
```

Comment: How should I implement it in C# ?
I can do   System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management")
but not sure how to combine it with my cmdlet

Comment: I assume there is some invoke-powershell going on, so instead of just your command, drop a semi-colon in between them to so they play nice in a one-liner.